# Rewriting a ? operator with an if-else in c#

Tags: c#, if-statement

Can I write this

```
 return (a, b) => (b == 0) ? 0: a / b;
```

With an `if-else` to the right of `(a, b) =>`

Comment: a float or an int or a double. I really just want to know how to do something like this

Comment: Depends, are you returning a `Func<double, double, double>` or are you returning a `Expression<Func<double, double, double>>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are returning a `Func<double, double, double>` it could be re-written as

```
return (a, b) =>
    {
     if(b == 0)
        return 0;
     else
        return a / b; 
    };
```

If you are returning a `Expression<Func<double, double, double>>` it is not very easy to do, you will need to create a custom [Expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expression(v=vs.110).aspx) by hand to represent the statement as there is no way to represent it in C#.

Have not tested it, but I think the Expression version would be

```
public Expression<Func<double, double, double>> IThinkThisWorks()
{
    var paramA = Expression.Parameter(typeof(double), "a");
    var paramB = Expression.Parameter(typeof(double), "b");
    var const0 = Expression.Constant(0.0);
    var test = Expression.Equal(paramA, paramB);
    var division = Expression.Divide(paramA, paramB);
    var ifCheck = Expression.IfThenElse(test, const0, division);
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<double, double, double>>(ifCheck, paramA, paramB);
}
```